# How do I distribute an executable for a c++/opengl game that uses dynamic libraries?

Tags: c++, distribution

I have a makefile that compiles everything fine but I'm wondering how I can package the dynamic libraries with the executable for distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you will have to check the license for each individual libraries regarding redistribution.

Then for Linux you will need a launch script that sets the library search path to where you packaged the libraries before launching the executable itself. The environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is what you want to set to where you put the libraries.

Your launch script can do extra checks to launch the proper executable for 32 or 64bits, x86 or 10+ variations of ARM, etc.

For Windows you can package the DLLs in the same directory as the executable.

On OSX the libraries are packaged inside the "application" (which is actually a directory) by XCode.

Note: you do not want to include the OpenGL libraries. Those depend on the graphic driver installed so you must use the system's installed libraries.